# "java *classname*" not working when i import something

Tags: java, class, cmd

I made a basic Java program that said "hello world"

I used the `javac` command to compile it and the `java` command to run it, everything worked, i made a "complex" (that needed to import random and scanner to work) program in NetBeans, exported it and compiled the source with the `javac` command in CMD but when i try to run it this happens:

[image]

It only happens when I try to use codes that use the "import" command in the file

edit:

i tried "javac asd.java" and "java Asd.java", both worked then i tried "java Asd" and "java asd", none work, it keeps giving me the error above, the code:

```
package asd;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Asd{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose a difficulty");
    boolean s = true;
    int v = 0;
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Very Easy/Easy/medium/hard/impossible/impossibler");
        System.out.print("I want it to be ");
        String x = scan.nextLine();
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("very easy")){
            v = 6;
            break;
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("easy")){
            v = 11;
            break;
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("medium")){
            v = 26;
            break;
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("hard")){
            v = 51;
            break;
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("impossible")){
            v = 101;
            break;
        }
        else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("impossibler")){
            s = false;
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("invalid difficulty");
        }

    }
    v--;
    int h = 0;
    int c = 0;
    if(s){
    System.out.println("Guess a number beween 0 and " + v);
    c = r.nextInt(v);
    //int i = 0;
    while (true) {
    String b = scan.nextLine();
    int g;
    try {        
        g = Integer.parseInt(b);
        if (g < c){
            System.out.println("Try higger");
        }
        else if (g > c){
            System.out.println("Maybe less");
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("please use a number");
    }}}
    else {
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and 999999999");
    while(true) {
    c = r.nextInt();
    if ((c < 0) && (c > 999999999)) {}
    else {
    break;
    }}
    while(true) {
    String b = scan.nextLine();
    try {
        int g;
        g = Integer.parseInt(b);
        if (g < c){
            System.out.println("Try higger");
        }
        else if (g > c){
            System.out.println("Maybe less");
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
            }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("please use a number");
        }}
    }
    System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    System.out.print("push enter to quit");
    String k = scan.nextLine();

}
}
```

it's a little game that i made, but it isn't just this code anything that i make that needs to import something just doesn't work when running it outside netbeans/eclipse

Comment: put your code here to get better answer.

Comment: Put your code **and your error messages** here.

Comment: try `java asd` (with lowercase 'a')

Comment: I you made a *"program in NetBeans"*, why didn't you just run it from within NetBeans.  When it's working, build the project, which will output a `jar` file in the `dist` directory...

Comment: If you may also provide the code you are trying to compile, that will be of much help, to explain as exactly what more you can do. For the start, `javac` requires the `filename.extension` as an argument, whereas `java` requires the `className` as an argument, to work.

Answer (score 5):

Java is case sensitive.

You compiled the class using ...

```
javac asd.java
```

The tried to run it using

```
java Asd
```

This won't work.

You should be using

```
java asd
```

Based on the information you have provided...

ps- You may want to take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: i tried both "java Asd" and "java asd" none work, for some reason it only works when i use codes that don't need to import anything like if i do "System.out.println("hi")" on the code it works, if i import anything like the Scanner it just doens't work

Comment: Change dir one level and the try java asd.Asd

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it , change the class name on the file and the constructor to something beginning with a capital letter(as naming convention).

Also, remember while windows is not case sensitive java is case sensitive no matter the platform!
Use case sensitivity at all times.

for a quick introduction to running classes and java configuration in the real world see this page
http://www.sidewinder11sucommanderxer.podserver.info/Linux-SidewinderPhotoColourBalancer.html

Answer (score 1):

may be class name and java file name is different

ex:

```
javac FileName.java
```

creates ClassName.class
 now,

```
 java ClassName
```

runs fine.(Remember case sensitive)

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

When you compile a .java file it gets converted to a corresponding .class file(bytecode). In your case asd.java will get converted to asd.class when you execute `javac asd.java`. Now when you call java interpreter it will interpret this bytecode(.class file) and hence you must give the same name to the Java interpreter as that of the .class file. (No need of .class extension just `java filename`)

So change your

```
java Asd
```

to

```
java asd
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers have been distracted by your confusing asd/Asd capitalisation stuff but the actual issue is where you're trying to run the program from. Because you've put your class within the "asd" package, you should refer to it using its full package and class designation.  What this means is that rather than running

```
java Asd
```

from the .../src/asd/ directory, you should run it as

```
java asd/Asd
```

from the .../src/ directory. That's -package-/-class-. So if you had a fuller package structure, like com.lucca.games.asd then you'd still use the "java" command in the "src" dir but your command would be

```
java com/lucca/games/asd/Asd
```